# How can i implement fluid in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I'm currently trying to implement a way to render images responsive. Right now i have different cropvariants in the TYPO3 image tool for different screensizes. The problem is i can't use fluid because of how the template is done. So right now I'm looking for a way to transfer the fluid code to Typoscript but sadly I'm not very experienced in Typoscript.

This is my fluid code:

```
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
<picture>
    <source srcset="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: settings.maxImgWidth, cropVariant: 'default')}" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '992', cropVariant: 'default')}, {f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '1984', cropVariant: 'default')} 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">
    <source srcset="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '768', cropVariant: 'tablet')}, {f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '1536', cropVariant: 'tablet')} 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '768', cropVariant: 'mobile')}, {f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: '1536', cropVariant: 'mobile')} 2x" media="(max-width: 767px)">
    <!---Fallback--->
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: settings.maxImgWidth, cropVariant: 'default')}" alt="{image.alternative}" longdesc="{image.description}" title="{image.title}">
</picture>
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You always could use a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` object in typoscript, but that wiold mean you have to provide all the necessary data used in the fluid as variables. That is even possible for defining variables for other FLUID templates.

But you probably are looking for realizing the same you have in FLUID in pure typoscript.
That is possible as it was used before FLUID (and without marker templates).

Just build a `COA` and use wraps everywhere.

Your outer structure is the `f:for` loop which iterates over some files.
Now you need this loop in typoscript. That could be a dataprocessor or a `FILES` object.

some inspirations (not tested):

```
temp.test = FILES 
temp.test { 
  references { 
    table = pages 
    uid.data = current:uid
    fieldName = media
  } 
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    wrap = <picture>|</picture>
    10 = IMGRESOURCE
    10 {
      wrap = <source srcset="|" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
      file { 
        import.data = file:current:uid 
        treatIdAsReference = 1 
        maxWidth < plugin.....settings.maxImgWidth
        cropVariant = default
      } 
    }
    20 = COA
    20 {
      noTrimWrap = |<source srcset="| 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">|
    }
    20.10 < .10
    20.10.file.width = 992m
    20.10.wrap = |,
    20.20 < .10
    20.20.file.width = 1984m

    30 < .20
    30 {
      noTrimWrap = |<source srcset="| 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">|
      10.file {
        cropVariant = tablet
        width = 768m
      }
      20.file {
        cropVariant = tablet
        width = 1536m
      }
    }
    40 < .30
    40 {
      noTrimWrap = |<source srcset="| 2x" media="(max-width: 768px)">|
      10.file.cropVariant = mobile
      20.file.cropVariant = mobile
    }
    // fallback
    50 = IMAGE
    50 {
      file { 
        import.data = file:current:uid 
        treatIdAsReference = 1 
        cropVariant = default
        width < plugin.......settings.maxImgWidth 
      }
      class = img-responsive
      altText.data = file:current:alternative
      titleText.data = file:current:title
    }
  }
}
```